# Read CSV file with features and labels in the same row in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow

I have a .csv file with around 5000 rows and 3757 columns. The first 3751 columns of each row are the features and the last 6 columns are the labels. Each row is a set of features-labels pair.

I'd like to know if there are built-in functions or any fast ways that I can:

1. Parse the first 3751 columns as features (these columns doesn't have headers)
2. Parse ANY of the last 6 columns as labels, which means that I'd like to take any of the last 6 columns out as a label for training.

Basically I want to train a DNN model with 3751 features and 1 label and I'd like the output of the parsing function be fed into the following function for training:

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": np.array(training_set.data)},
      y=np.array(training_set.target),
      num_epochs=None,
      shuffle=True)
```

I know some functions like "tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header" can do similar things but it is already deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into `tf.data.Dataset`'s input pipelines ([LINK](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)). What you basically do is you can read a csv file, possibly batch/shuffle/map it somehow and create an iterator over the dataset. Whenever you evaluate `iterator.get_next()`, you get a number of lines from your csv which is equal to batch size. Concerning your separation of features and labels, you can then simply access single elements of the batch with standard python syntax, e.g. `features = batch[:-6]` and `label = batch[-1]` and feed them to whatever function you like.

On the tensorflow site, there's an in-depth tutorial about how to use these input pipelines ([LINK](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)).

Answer (score 0):

```
train_features_interim = []
  train_labels_interim = []
  with open(train_file) as f:
      csvreader = csv.reader(f)
      for row in csvreader:
          train_features_interim.append(row)  

  train_features_interim = pd.DataFrame(train_features_interim)      
  a = len(train_features_interim.columns)-6
  train_labels_interim = train_features_interim.iloc[:, a:a+1]   #train one label first
  train_features_interim = train_features_interim.iloc[:, :a]
  train_features_numpy = np.asarray(train_features_interim, dtype=np.float32)
  train_labels_numpy = np.asarray(train_labels_interim, dtype=np.float32)
```

I have this working now. Though it is not very clean but it works. I can tune the "a:a+1" part to decide how many( or which) columns I'd like to put inot train_labels_interim.